# Show that $\varphi(x,ix)=0 $ iff $\varphi$ is the real part of a complex inner product in $E$.

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $\varphi$ be a real inner product $\varphi:E \times  E \to \mathbb{R}$ in a complex vector space $E$. Show that $\varphi(x,ix)=0 \  (\forall x\in E) $ iff $\varphi$ is the real part of a complex inner product in $E$.

I found it easy enough to show the if part, but I have no clue on the only if. Any hints?

Comment: You want to prove this: Assume $\varphi(x,ix) = 0$ for all $x \in E$. Then there exists a complex inner product $\psi : E \times E \to \mathbb C$ so that
$\operatorname{Re} \psi(x,y) = \varphi(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in E$.  I would try a "polarization identity".  This writes the inner product $\langle x,y \rangle$ as a linear combination of the squared norms of $x+y, x-y, x+iy, x-iy$